# why messages logs are zero

Tags: linux, rhel, logs, rsyslog, logrotate

we have linux machine:

```
more /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

all message files under /var/log are ZERO

how it could be ?
what is wrong here ?

```
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Aug 13  2018 messages-20180819
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Aug 13  2018 maillog-20180819
-rw-------. 1 root   root    136530 Aug 19  2018 cron-20180819
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Aug 19  2018 spooler-20180826
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Aug 19  2018 secure-20180826
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Aug 19  2018 messages-20180826
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Aug 19  2018 maillog-20180826
-rw-------. 1 root   root    159928 Aug 26  2018 cron-20180826
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Aug 26  2018 messages-20180903
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Aug 26  2018 maillog-20180903
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Aug 26  2018 spooler-20180903
-rw-------. 1 root   root      6834 Sep  2  2018 secure-20180903
-rw-------. 1 root   root    182433 Sep  3  2018 cron-20180903
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Sep  3  2018 messages-20180909
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Sep  3  2018 maillog-20180909
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Sep  3  2018 spooler-20180909
-rw-------. 1 root   root       294 Sep  4 12:23 secure-20180909
-rw-------. 1 root   root    136833 Sep  9 03:41 cron-20180909
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root      4096 Sep  9 03:41 rhsm
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Sep  9 03:41 spooler
-rw-------. 1 root   root         0 Sep  9 03:41 messages
-rw-------. 1 root   root       165 Sep 12 12:00 maillog
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root   root        40 Oct 14 12:16 mcspace
-rw-------. 1 root   utmp      3072 Nov 13 09:44 btmp
-rw-------. 1 root   root       527 Jan 17 11:32 yum.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root     34601 Jan 31 09:14 Xorg.0.log
drwxr-x---. 2 root   root        94 Feb 15 10:00 audit
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root     93562 Feb 25 13:32 vmware-vmsvc.log
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root      4096 Mar  1 23:53 sa
-rw-------. 1 root   root   2328945 Mar  5 11:01 cron
-rw-------. 1 root   root    116853 Mar  5 11:07 secure
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root   utmp     59520 Mar  5 11:07 wtmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    295504 Mar  5 11:07 lastlog
```

Comment: Probably just nothing getting logged.

Comment: but OS performed reboot before week , so how it can be ?

Comment: I also do logger "test" and more messages , but file is null

Comment: insufficient disk space under /var  or syslog-ng bug where it starts working after syslog restart. Heads or tails?

Comment: /var is ok no problem of disk space

Comment: I also restart systemctl restart rsyslog

Comment: @yael what do you have within `/etc/rsyslog.conf`  Also, what does `systemctl status rsyslog`  tell you? Is there any file named syslog within `/etc/logrotate.d/`  ?